# GitHub Desktop / Git Shell: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054

Tags: ssl, github, git-shell, github-desktop

Since this morning, when I try to sync from GitHub Desktop after creating a commit, I sometimes get the message:

[image]

When I try to push the commit in Git Shell, I get:

> SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054

[image]

What could be the issue?

It takes around one or two minute between the time I try to push and the time I get the error message (in GitHub Desktop or Git Shell), so I suspect some connection issues on GitHub side (I have checked the robustness of the connection on my side), but I find the message sibylline.

I use GitHub Desktop with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

Change URL from https to http, for me it worked. There must be problem with ssl tunnel. But currently you can start it by switching to http.

Answer (score 0):

I got here because I was looking for a solution, too. I have got an **SSL read: error....** (identical to yours) returned as well when I was trying to push a commit. The reason might have been some big files in the commit that you were trying to push to github.

For me, I followed steps https://git-lfs.github.com provides and it seems to solve my problem.